# rails/roda/sinatra/... / normalize object keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, sinatra

we often face irregularities from the object we can receive (stringified keys, or the opposite), so each specs, services, etc.. needs to handle it case y case; not blocking but can be a time consuming, at least it feels awkward to wonder everytime it happens what we did the other time

What would be the best way to introduce such normalization at the highest level (stringify_keys in an initializer?) ? Should the Hash class be extended ?

Comment: This is already implemented in Rails. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html

Comment: @PaulByrne yep this is exactly the use i was trying to avoid. correct me if i'm wrong, you have to specifically pass all hashes in that method; this is not a global setup

Comment: No that's not exactly right. In Rails the params object that you have access to in the controller will behave in the way you're describing, which is the boundary you probably want this functionality. Maybe you can describe more specifically the use case you have in your current application. Where does the data you're talking about come from?

Comment: Humm yes i will rewrite the question. Let's say we're not using controllers, and not rails ( i named roda/sinatra,etc..). Within rails you're kinda stuck once you work with api (json parse will always be stringified), or build object from the ground up and use it in services or likes. Once all those approaches are mixed; you tender to wonder wether its stringified or sym'ed. Not a big deal but perfectible

Comment: Hi Ben, do you have an example of where this might occur? Even one example might clarify things a bit / give a likely course of action.